# OpenSSL x509 policy_anything

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to sign a CSR with a self-created Certificate Authority (CA) that I have, and I want the policy to be set to `policy_anything`.

the current command i have is:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt
```

The commands that I find that should work are adding

```
-config /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf -policy policy_anything
```

but it gives me an error, saying that the `-config` command is invalid/unknown or the `-policy` command is invalid/unknown.

Any suggestion? thanks
Mihai

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `-config` and `-policy` are flags for `openssl ca`, not `openssl x509`.

There are many ways to sign a CSR with `openssl`, e.g. `ca`, `req -x509`, `x509 -req`, and setting policy seems easiest with `ca`.

Try

`openssl ca -policy policy_anything -config /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf -days 365 -cert ca.crt -keyfile ca.key -in server.csr -out server.crt`

Comment: Running the `openssl ca` command above results with an error message stating that ./demoCA directory does not exist. Is there some sort of step missing?